# How can I get the navigation drawer to work after navigating through several fragments in my Android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer for my app. It functions well when I initially open the app. I can navigate from the `Home Fragment` to the `Borrow Fragment` using the navigation drawer. However, after several navigations, it stops working.

I have two fragments within the navigation drawer: `Home Fragment` and `Borrow Fragment`. The `Home Fragment` leads to the `Book Info Fragment`, which, in turn, leads to the `Maps Fragment`. The `Maps Fragment` eventually leads to the `Borrow Fragment`. The navigation happens using the navigation directions.

When I'm in the `Borrow Fragment` through this route, I can't navigate back to the `Home Fragment` using the navigation drawer. It only pops up to the Home Fragment. Any insights on what might be causing this issue?

`activity_main_drawer.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_borrow"
            android:icon="@drawable/book_icon"
            android:title="@string/menu_borrow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting"
            android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

`mobile_navigation.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.bookradar.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_book_info"
            app:destination="@id/nav_book_info"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"

            />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_borrow"
        android:name="com.example.bookradar.BorrowFragment"
        android:label="BorrowFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_borrow">
        <argument
            android:name="item"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="com.example.bookradar.BookInfo"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_maps"
        android:name="com.example.bookradar.MapsFragment"
        android:label="MapsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_maps">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_maps_to_nav_borrow"
            app:destination="@id/nav_borrow" />
        <argument
            android:name="books"
            app:argType="com.example.bookradar.BookInfo[]"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_book_info"
        android:name="com.example.bookradar.BookInfoFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_book_info"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_book_info">
        <argument
            android:name="item"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="com.example.bookradar.model.BookModel"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_book_info_to_nav_maps"
            app:destination="@id/nav_maps" />
    </fragment>


</navigation>
```

`MainActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        /*binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }*/

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_borrow, R.id.nav_maps
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

`HomeFragment.kt`:

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var adapter: MyBookRecyclerViewAdapter
    private lateinit var apiKey: String

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var bookList: MutableList<BookModel>
    var rootView: View? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        if (rootView != null) {
            return rootView as View
        }
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        rootView = binding.root

        apiKey = "KakaoAK " + BuildConfig.KAKAO_API
        val searchBar = binding.searchBook
        recyclerView = binding.listBook
        bookList = mutableListOf<BookModel>()
        adapter = MyBookRecyclerViewAdapter(bookList,
            object : MyBookRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(item: BookModel) {
                    val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionNavHomeToNavBookInfo(item)
                    findNavController().navigate(action)
                }
            })
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        searchBar.clearFocus()
        var job: Job? = null
        searchBar.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
                    throwable.printStackTrace()
                }
                val prevListSize = bookList.size
                bookList.clear()
                adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, prevListSize)
                job?.cancel()
                job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + coroutineExceptionHandler) {
                    try {
                        var response: BookListModel? = null
                        var prevSize = 0
                        var page = 1
                        while (response == null || response.meta.is_end.not()) {
                            response = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().getBooks(apiKey, query, page++)
                            bookList.addAll(response.documents)
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(prevSize, bookList.size)
                            }
                            prevSize = bookList.size
                        }
                    } catch (_: CancellationException) {
                        Log.d("Coroutine", "Job cancelled")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("Network Error", "Error fetching data", e)
                    }
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                // false if no custom behavior is defined.
                return false
            }

        })

        /* val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
         homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
             textView.text = it
         }*/
        return rootView as View
    }


}
```

`BookInfoFragment.kt`:

```kotlin
class BookInfoFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentBookInfoBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentBookInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val item = arguments?.getParcelable<BookModel>("item")
        binding.textBookTitle.text = item?.title
        binding.textAuthor.text =
            item?.authors?.joinToString(", ") ?: getString(R.string.unknown_author)
        binding.textPublisher.text = item?.publisher
        binding.textIsbn.text = item?.isbn
        binding.textContent.text = item?.contents
        // implementation for fetching book info
        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            val crawler = Crawler()
            val isbns = binding.textIsbn.text.split(' ')
            var bInfos: ArrayList<BookInfo>?
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    bInfos = crawler.getBookInfos(isbns)?.let { it1 -> ArrayList(it1) }
                    bInfos?.forEach {
                        it.book = item
                    }
                }
                if (bInfos != null) {
                    val action = BookInfoFragmentDirections.actionNavBookInfoToNavMaps(bInfos!!.toTypedArray())
                    findNavController().navigate(action)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.no_book_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("BookInfoFragment", "No book found")
                }
            }
        }
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(item?.thumbnail)
            .apply(bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(25, 3)))
            .into(binding.imageBookCoverBlur)
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(item?.thumbnail)
            .into(binding.imageBookCover)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(item: BookModel) = BookInfoFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable("item", item)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`MapsFragment.kt`:

```kotlin
class MapsFragment : Fragment(), GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
        /**
         * Manipulates the map once available.
         * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
         * In this case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
         * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to
         * install it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the
         * user has installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
         */
        val school = LatLng(37.500062,126.868063)
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(school, 20f))
        arguments?.getParcelableArray("books")?.forEach {
            val book = it as BookInfo
            val marker = googleMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(book.library!!.location).title(book.library!!.getName(requireContext())).snippet(book.loc)
            )
            marker?.tag = book
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        Log.d("MapsFragment", arguments?.getParcelableArray("books")?.size.toString())
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)

    }

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker): Boolean {
        val book = p0.tag as BookInfo
        ModalBottomSheet().apply {
            this.book = book
        }.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, ModalBottomSheet.TAG)
        return true
    }
}
class ModalBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    lateinit var book: BookInfo
    private lateinit var binding: BottomSheetBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = BottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.textLibraryName.text = book.library!!.getName(requireContext())
        binding.textLibraryLocation.text = book.loc
        binding.buttonBorrow.setOnClickListener {
            MapsFragmentDirections.actionNavMapsToNavBorrow(book).let {
                (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)!!
                    .findNavController().navigate(it)
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }


    companion object {
        const val TAG = "ModalBottomSheet"
    }
}
```

`BorrowFragment.kt`:

```kotlin
class BorrowFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentBorrowBinding
    private var adapter: MemoAdapter? = null
    private var itemID: Int = 0
    private var dbHelper: DBHelper? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentBorrowBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val bInfo = arguments?.getParcelable<BookInfo>("item")
        if (bInfo != null) {
            val memo = Memo(
                bInfo.book!!.title!!,
                bInfo.library!!.getName(requireContext()),
                LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE).toString(),
                LocalDate.now().plusDays(7).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE).toString(),
                bInfo.book!!.thumbnail!!
            )
            showManualEntry({ m ->
                addMemo(m)
            }, memo)
        }


        val dataList = mutableListOf<MutableMap<String, String>>()

        dbHelper = DBHelper(activity)
        val db = dbHelper?.readableDatabase
        val cursor = db?.rawQuery(DBContract.SQL_LOAD, null, null)
        while (cursor?.moveToNext()!!) {
            val item = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
            item["id"] = cursor.getInt(0).toString()
            item["title"] = cursor.getString(1)!!
            item["library"] = cursor.getString(2)!!
            item["borrow"] = cursor.getString(3)!!
            item["due"] = cursor.getString(4)!!
            item["image"] = cursor.getString(5)!!
            dataList.add(item)
            itemID = cursor.getInt(0)
        }
        cursor.close()

        adapter = MemoAdapter(this, dataList)
        binding.borrowingBookList.adapter = adapter

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            showManualEntry({ memo ->
                addMemo(memo)
            })
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    /**
     * Calculate duration between two dates in days
     * @param fromTime start date
     * @param toTime end date
     * @return duration between two dates in days
     */
    fun calculateDuration(fromTime: LocalDate, toTime: LocalDate): Long {
        fromTime.until(toTime, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS)
        return fromTime.until(toTime, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    }

    private fun addMemo(memo: Memo) {
        val item = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        itemID++
        item["id"] = itemID.toString()
        item["title"] = memo.title
        item["library"] = memo.library
        item["borrow"] = memo.borrow
        item["due"] = memo.due
        item["image"] = memo.image
        adapter!!.datas.add(item)
        adapter!!.notifyItemChanged(itemID)

        DBContract.insertMemo(requireContext(), itemID, memo)
    }

    private fun calendarClickListener(
        eBinding: EditLayoutBinding,
        targetView: TextView
    ): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            val today = LocalDate.now()
            DatePickerDialog(
                requireContext(),
                { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    val setDate = Calendar.getInstance()
                    setDate.set(year, month, dayOfMonth)

                    targetView.text = LocalDate.of(
                        setDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        setDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                        setDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                    ).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)

                    // calculate duration and update number picker
                    if (eBinding.editTextDueDate.text.isNotEmpty() && eBinding.editTextBorrowDate.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val borrowDate = LocalDate.parse(
                            eBinding.editTextBorrowDate.text,
                            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
                        )
                        val dueDate =
                            LocalDate.parse(
                                eBinding.editTextDueDate.text,
                                DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
                            )
                        val duration = calculateDuration(borrowDate, dueDate)
                        eBinding.numberPickerDuration.value = duration.toInt()
                    }
                }, today.year, today.monthValue, today.dayOfMonth
            ).show()

        }
    }

    /**
     * Show alert dialog to manually enter the borrowed book information
     * @param callback callback function to handle the result
     * @param memo default values to show
     */
    fun showManualEntry(callback: (Memo) -> Unit, memo: Memo? = null) {
        val eBinding = EditLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            // configure duration number picker
            numberPickerDuration.run {
                // min and max value of duration
                minValue = 1
                maxValue = 100

                setOnValueChangedListener { _, _, newVal ->
                    val borrowDate = LocalDate.parse(
                        editTextBorrowDate.text,
                        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE
                    )
                    val dueDate = borrowDate.plusDays(newVal.toLong())
                    editTextDueDate.setText(dueDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
                }
            }
            imageButtonCalendarBorrowDate.setOnClickListener(
                calendarClickListener(
                    this,
                    editTextBorrowDate
                )
            )
            imageButtonCalendarDueDate.setOnClickListener(
                calendarClickListener(
                    this,
                    editTextDueDate
                )
            )

            // use provided values if exists
            if (memo != null) {
                editTextBookTitle.setText(memo.title)
                editTextLibrary.setText(memo.library)
                editTextBorrowDate.setText(memo.borrow)
                editTextDueDate.setText(memo.due)
                numberPickerDuration.value = calculateDuration(
                    LocalDate.parse(memo.borrow, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE),
                    LocalDate.parse(memo.due, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                ).toInt()
            } else {
                // set the default date of due date to today
                editTextBorrowDate.setText(
                    LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE).toString()
                )
                editTextDueDate.setText(
                    LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE).toString()
                )
            }
        }

        // show alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder(activity).run {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.manual_entry))
            setView(eBinding.root)
            setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                val title = eBinding.editTextBookTitle.text.toString()
                val library = eBinding.editTextLibrary.text.toString()
                val borrow = eBinding.editTextBorrowDate.text.toString()
                val due = eBinding.editTextDueDate.text.toString()
                callback(Memo(title, library, borrow, due, memo?.image ?: ""))
            }
            setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            show()
        }

    }

    fun delMemo(id: Int) {
        val db = dbHelper?.writableDatabase
        db?.delete(DBContract.TABLE_NAME, "id=$id", null)
    }

    fun editMemo(pos: Int, memo: Memo) {
        adapter!!.datas[pos]["title"] = memo.title
        adapter!!.datas[pos]["library"] = memo.library
        adapter!!.datas[pos]["borrow"] = memo.borrow
        adapter!!.datas[pos]["due"] = memo.due
        adapter!!.notifyItemChanged(pos)

        DBContract.updateMemo(requireContext(), pos, memo)
    }
}
```

If my question is not clear, or I'm not giving enough context, I'm sorry. I'm a novice here :(

I clicked on the Home button to go from the `Borrow Fragment` to the `Home Fragment`, but it doesn't do anything. I can only pop up to the Home Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating new nav graph instance. Just use `Fragment.findNavController()`

Use:

```
findNavController().navigate(
                MapsFragmentDirections.actionNavMapsToNavBorrow(book)
            )
```

instead of

```
MapsFragmentDirections.actionNavMapsToNavBorrow(book).let {
                (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)!!
                    .findNavController().navigate(it)
                dismiss()
            }
```

Also, you can add `android:menuCategory="secondary"` in menu items. When using secondary category menu item fragment back stack is resets.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention! I made the adjustments as you suggested, but it seems that things haven't changed :( . This is really driving me crazy...

Comment: @selagismo You can try to add android:menuCategory="secondary" in menu items, in this way drawer fragments back stacks are reset.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem!